# Getting only date time mm dd yyy hh mm ss

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How to get this: `2011-02-09 13:09:00`

I want this format in sql:

```
MM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS 
07/22/2014 01:51:57 AM/PM
```

Comment: Either [one of the pre-defined `CONVERT` styles fits your needs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), or you'll have to do a lot of string fiddling yourself. Why don't you do this in your **front-end** application (C#, PHP, Ruby - whatever)?

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

or try this:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = Getdate(); 
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(32) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dt, 109); 

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt, 101) + ' '+RIGHT('0'+
                                     Substring(@time, Len(@time) - 
                                     Charindex(' ', Reverse(@time)) +2, 
                                     Charindex(' ', Reverse(@time)) - 
                                     Charindex(':', Reverse(@time))-1),8) 
       + ' '+RIGHT(@time, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this sql, if you are querying the data:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS'
```